# How to use drag and drop with HierarchicalDataTemplate and TreeView Items hosting TextBlocks using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a Hierarchical Data Template that I would like to allow for drag and drop functionality. I am using TextBlocks to display the TreeView item data. However, the drag and drop functionality is not working at all right now.

I tried modifying the TreeView Style Template here with the drag and drop events but nothing was firing. I suspect it would be because I need to use the TextBlock?

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
 <EventSetter Event="Drag_Over" Handler="Drag_Over_Event"/>
 <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="Drop_Event"/>
 <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="Mouse_Move_Event"/>
 </Style>
```

This is my HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Situation.TopLevelSituationList}" AllowDrop="True">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupSubGroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubGroups}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupDecision}" ItemsSource="{Binding Decisions}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBaseStyling}" Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
```

I consulted some resources but couldn't seem to get the drag and drop working, regardless.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Is mouse move really not working? The template stuff still ends up in a treeviewitem.  Or else there'd be nowhere to put the children.  I would think what you've shown us should give you a working event handler for something as simple as mousemove.

Comment: I have the MouseMove now working.